# updating data in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I just want to ask if you could help me in my task in symfony2. I'm developing a comment section like you can write a comment in a text box in a modal and then once you click "Add Comment", the comment you've written will be stored in the table called edi_864824 where it's inside the column named "comments" in its corresponding id (ediTransactionId). But I'm only new to symfony2 framework that's why I'm really having a tough time doing this. Please help me correct my code.
Thanks

This is my route:

```
matrix_edi_addComment:
pattern: /addComment/{id}-{url}
defaults: { _controller: "MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:addComment" }
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function addCommentAction($id, $url, Request $request) {

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$trans = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:Edi864824')->findOneByEdiTransactionId($id);

$comment = $this->get('request')->request->get('comment');

$trans->setComment($comment);

$em->persist($trans);

$em->flush();

$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Your comment has been saved.');

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($url));

}
```

This is my Repository:

```
public function getOutputComment($transDate){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery(

        'SELECT partial a.{ediTransactionId, transactionDate, isaNumber, gsNumber, fileName},
                partial b.{ediTransactionId, tradingPartner, transDate, issue, referenceNumberId, comment},
                partial c.{referenceNumberId, transCn, poNumber, asnNumber}
         FROM MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransaction a
         JOIN a.edi864824 b
         JOIN b.referenceNumber c
         WHERE a.ediTransactionId = b.ediTransactionId
         AND b.referenceNumberId = c.referenceNumberId
         AND b.transDate LIKE :transDate
         ORDER BY b.transDate DESC')

    ->setParameter('transDate', "%$transDate%");

    return $query->getResult();

}
```

This is in the twig query (inputComment.html.twig) for the other page where the modal is located for the comment to be written and redirects to the new twig query (outputComment.html.twig) which has the comment column in it.

```
<a data-href="{{ path('matrix_edi_addComment', { 'id':trans.ediTransactionId,'url': 'matrix_edi_outputComment' }) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><center><i class="fa fa-comment" style="color: #1975A3;"></i></center></a>
```

Comment: please accept my answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling your code should be something like this:

```
public function addCommentAction($ediTransactionId, Request $request){

   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $trans = $em->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:ediTransaction')->findOneBy($ediTransactionId);

   $comment = $request->get("comment"); // <-- I changed this line
   $trans->setComment($comment); // <-- I changed this line
   $em->persist($trans);
   $em->flush();

   $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
   $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Your comment has been saved.');

   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('matrix_edi_outputComment'));     

}
```

PS, you don't need the `$em->persist($trans);` since the `$trans` object is already registered with Doctrine (since you fetched it earlier)

Comment: Richard, can you recheck my code. I edited my Action and twig for clearer presentation of my program. Kindly tell me what are the corrections needed to be done. Thanks

Comment: First you have to say what is not working? Also, you should ask a coworker for help to set up xdebug, then you would solve these problems way easier ☺️

Comment: Controller "Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Controller\MatrixController::addCommentAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$comment" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

I got this error from following this code:
$trans->setComment($comment);

In your correction, you suggested that I should change that line, I don't know how actually. Sorry

Comment: Hi, I updatet the question, please take a look... Also all of these problems are documented in depth in the Symfonys documentation, you should really take a look and read trough it...